# Wondering on how to store an answer in an input box

Tags: php

The problem im having is i want the user to input the answer to the input box and when submit button is clicked the box should highlight green if correct and red if incorrect.

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
    <h2>Challenge 2</h2>
        <p>Key: puck</p>
        <p>Message: lbcd uiqvh njohy oygncvh vg

        </p>

                Answer:<br>
                <input type="text" name="answer2" value="">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Expected results should give the user an indication if they are wrong or right in answering the question.

Comment: you need to demonstrate something that you've attempted, or a problem you've run into - not just ask us to write code for you.  Is your output expected after a submission to php and some answer checking in the database, or is it all front end for example.  You need to be more specific and then post some code that isn't working

Comment: If you want to highlight the input box without submitting the page, you're going to have to use JS and AJAX, then handle the response coming back accordingly

Comment: It would be a stored answer in the code that it can do a check against

Comment: So you want to pull down all the answers, as some sort of JS object first, then on submit check against that object?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use JavaScript

```
Answer:<br>
<input type="text" id="answer2" name="answer2" value="">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="checkIfCorrect()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function checkIfCorrect(){
   var answerValue = document.getElementById("answer2").value;
   if(answerValue == "expectedAnswer")
     doSomething();
}
</script>
```

However this means the "expectedResult" will be inside the code that is sent to the user and can be easily viewed inside the developer console. If you want to hide the value you're looking for from the user you will need to use ajax.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp